# How to make Constructor parameters available to prototype functions JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

In the simplified example below, the `MyService.doSomething` function has access to `someDependency` because the prototype function is defined within the `MyService` constructor.

```
// Define MyService Class
function MyService(someDependency) {
   MyService.prototype.doSomething = function(){
      return someDependency.doSomething();
   }
}
```

To use `MyService` with a given dependency:

```
// Construct MyService
var myService = new MyService(someDependency);
var result = myService.doSomething();
```

I am pretty sure that this is bad practice but how do I make the constructor parameter `someDependency` available to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should initialize the prototype at the same time as when you define the constructor, instead of redefining it every time you create a new instance.

```
// Define MyService Class
function MyService(someDependency) {
    // ...
}

MyService.prototype.doSomething = function(){
    // ...
}
```

After that, all that remains to go is to copy the parameters into instance variables explicitly

```
// Define MyService Class
function MyService(someDependency) {
   this.someDependency = someDependency;
}

MyService.prototype.doSomething = function(){
  return this.someDependency.doSomething();
}
```

All instance variables are piublic. If you want you can use a naming convention (like starting with an underscore) to mark "pseudo-private" variables.

If you want to use the function parameter directly instead of assigning instance variables you can have the methods be closures belonging to your object instead of a sharred function at the prototype. This lets you use variables from the constructor (and those variables are private!) but makes it harder to create subclasses.

```
function MyService(someDependency) {
    this.doSomething = function(){
        return someDependency.doSomething();
    };
}
```

The version with closures can be slower than the prototype version but I wouldn't worry about i most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the common way is - if an object has a property, it should actually *have* that property.

```
function MyService(someDependency) {
    this.dependency = someDependency; // set it on the object
}

MyService.prototype.doSomething = function(){
   return this.dependency.doSomething(); // now the prototype can access it
}
```

You're also right in that the way you're currently doing it is bad in at least one sense - the extra closure makes it slower. As for readability - I find it harder to read but that's debatable. It also makes subclassing and extending via prototypical inheritance a lot harder.